# My program is giving getche error

Tags: c++

I Have made a program that outputs greater number in array..but i have an error in the end of program kindly tell me what is the error..

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

void func(int array[])
{
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if (array[i]>temp)
        {
            temp = array[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "The biggest number is: " << temp << endl;
}

void main()
{
    int arr[10];
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    func(arr);
    getche();
}
```

Comment: Please fix your spacing, it's impossible to read your code.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Well whats the error ?

Comment: What is the details of error message? Which platform and compiler do you use? Note that conio.h is not availble on Linux and Dev-C++ below 4.9.

Answer (score -1):

Well there are logical problems which i wont correct, but the below code executes (at least) in C++. You are mixing C and C++. Comparing the code would give you what changed to make it compile.

```
#include<iostream>


using namespace std;

void func(int array[])
{
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if (array[i]>temp)
        {
            temp = array[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "The biggest number is: " << temp << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    func(arr);
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Mixing C and C++ is perfectly possible. This is not the problem. I think the issue is mixing stream-based output and direct (unbuffered) reading from the input. But I am not sure as the author did not state clearly his/her problem